# Get json file with ajax in react

Tags: reactjs, json

I need to get JSON file with AJAX. I have my data locally in data.json. It looks like

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "favourite": false,
    "name": "Gilbert Morton",
    "age": 30,
    "phone": "(369) 432-9206",
    "image": "sheep",
    "phrase": "Japman somam mes lizmasapa om zefopi ki wa ogju mofrajnir denba uc famoso opeipu woul.",
    "video": "shoe"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "favourite": true,
    "name": "Jeffery Davidson",
    "age": 57,
    "phone": "(415) 670-6901",
    "image": "pig",
    "phrase": "Lejtefup boc hi ricge tela mo ragdi vutomeh kuhup veosubu pe ceso juhzustum ipagagcub fu."
  }
]
```

I am doing in the following way

```
async function getUser() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/data.json");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(response);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
},[])
```

I got response, status 200, but on data Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. What I do wrong?

Comment: You might need a relative path when fetching data.json or make sure it's accessible at the path specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it's working properly however I see an issue with your **useEffect** you got an extra bracket after the dependency array

also if you're using create react app make sure your json file is located inside your public folder